# Change the timestamp to UTC format in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input dataframe(**ip_df**), data in this dataframe looks like as below:

```
id            timestamp_value
1       2017-08-01T14:30:00+05:30
2       2017-08-01T14:30:00+06:30
3       2017-08-01T14:30:00+07:30
```

I need to create a new dataframe(**op_df**), wherein i need to convert timestamp value to UTC format. So final output dataframe will look like as below:

```
id            timestamp_value
1       2017-08-01T09:00:00+00:00
2       2017-08-01T08:00:00+00:00
3       2017-08-01T07:00:00+00:00
```

I want to achieve it using PySpark. Can someone please help me with it? Any help will be appericiated.

Answer (score 13):

If you absolutely need the timestamp to be formatted exactly as indicated, namely, with the timezone represented as "+00:00", I think using a UDF as [already suggested](/questions/45434538/change-the-timestamp-to-utc-format-in-pyspark/#45438082) is your best option.

However, if you can tolerate a slightly different representation of the timezone, e.g. either "+0000" (no colon separator) or "Z", it's possible to do this without a UDF, which may perform significantly better for you depending on the size of your dataset.

Given the following representation of data

```
+---+-------------------------+
|id |timestamp_value          |
+---+-------------------------+
|1  |2017-08-01T14:30:00+05:30|
|2  |2017-08-01T14:30:00+06:30|
|3  |2017-08-01T14:30:00+07:30|
+---+-------------------------+
```

as given by:

```
l = [(1, '2017-08-01T14:30:00+05:30'), (2, '2017-08-01T14:30:00+06:30'), (3, '2017-08-01T14:30:00+07:30')]
ip_df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['id', 'timestamp_value'])
```

where `timestamp_value` is a `String`, you could do the following (this uses [to_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp) and [session local timezone support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18936) which were introduced in Spark 2.2):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, date_format
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
op_df = ip_df.select(
    date_format(
        to_timestamp(ip_df.timestamp_value, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"), 
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    ).alias('timestamp_value'))
```

which yields:

```
+------------------------+
|timestamp_value         |
+------------------------+
|2017-08-01T09:00:00+0000|
|2017-08-01T08:00:00+0000|
|2017-08-01T07:00:00+0000|
+------------------------+
```

or, slightly differently:

```
op_df = ip_df.select(
    date_format(
        to_timestamp(ip_df.timestamp_value, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"), 
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
    ).alias('timestamp_value'))
```

which yields:

```
+--------------------+
|timestamp_value     |
+--------------------+
|2017-08-01T09:00:00Z|
|2017-08-01T08:00:00Z|
|2017-08-01T07:00:00Z|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: There's also a to_utc_timestamp function but it requires the local timezone as an argument. As a result I believe setting the session timezone config should be better. It might be necessary to add the following parameters as well:

```config('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=UTC')``` and 
```config('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=UTC')```

Answer (score 6):

You can use *parser* and *tz* in dateutil library.
I assume you have Strings and you want a String Column :

```
from dateutil import parser, tz
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf

# Create UTC timezone
utc_zone =  tz.gettz('UTC')

# Create UDF function that apply on the column
# It takes the String, parse it to a timestamp, convert to UTC, then convert to String again
func = udf(lambda x: parser.parse(x).astimezone(utc_zone).isoformat(),  StringType())

# Create new column in your dataset
df = df.withColumn("new_timestamp",func(col("timestamp_value")))
```

It gives this result :

```
<pre>
+---+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|id |timestamp_value          |new_timestamp            |
+---+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|1  |2017-08-01T14:30:00+05:30|2017-08-01T09:00:00+00:00|
|2  |2017-08-01T14:30:00+06:30|2017-08-01T08:00:00+00:00|
|3  |2017-08-01T14:30:00+07:30|2017-08-01T07:00:00+00:00|
+---+-------------------------+-------------------------+
</pre>
```

Finally you can drop and rename :

```
df = df.drop("timestamp_value").withColumnRenamed("new_timestamp","timestamp_value")
```

Comment: I get `'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'read'` when I try on spark 3.0.2

Comment: I gotta say for such a simple requirement, its a bit painful we have to resort to a udf. Thanks for working this out none the less!