# TimeStampType in Pyspark with datetime tzaware objects

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark

I have the following issue I cannot fully understand in Pyspark. I have the following datetime objects

```
utc_now = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=tz.tzutc())
utc_now # datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 12, 13, 9, 52, 785007, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

and I create a spark DataFrame

```
data_df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(date=utc_now)])
```

when I try to show the dataframe

```
data_df.show(10, False)
```

the column containing the data is in local time that is 2 hours front

```
>>> data_df.show(10, False)
+--------------------------+
|date                      |
+--------------------------+
|2018-02-12 15:09:52.785007|
+--------------------------+
```

and collecting the data has shifted time in the datetime object two hours front

```
>>> data_df.collect()
[Row(date=datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 12, 15, 9, 52, 785007))]
```

Zone info is also removed. Can this behavior be altered when casting to `TimestampType`?

Answer (score 10):

`TimestampType` in pyspark is not tz aware like in Pandas rather it passes `long int`s and displays them according to your machine's local time zone (by default).

That being said, you can change your spark session time zone, using `'spark.sql.session.timeZone'`

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
from pyspark.sql import Row

utc_now = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=tz.tzutc())
print(utc_now)

spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'Europe/Paris')
data_df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(date=utc_now)])
data_df.show(10, False)
print(data_df.collect())

    2018-02-12 20:41:16.270386+00:00
    +--------------------------+
    |date                      |
    +--------------------------+
    |2018-02-12 21:41:16.270386|
    +--------------------------+

    [Row(date=datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 12, 21, 41, 16, 270386))]


spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
data_df2 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(date=utc_now)])
data_df2.show(10, False)
print(data_df2.collect())

    +--------------------------+
    |date                      |
    +--------------------------+
    |2018-02-12 20:41:16.270386|
    +--------------------------+

    [Row(date=datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 12, 21, 41, 16, 270386))]
```

As you can see Spark considers it as UTC but serves it back in the local timezone since Python still has time zone 'Europe/Paris'

```
import os, time
os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC'
time.tzset()
utc_now = datetime.now()
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
data_df2 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(date=utc_now)])
data_df2.show(10, False)
print(data_df2.collect())

    +--------------------------+
    |date                      |
    +--------------------------+
    |2018-02-12 20:41:16.807757|
    +--------------------------+

    [Row(date=datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 12, 20, 41, 16, 807757))]
```

Moreover, `pyspark.sql.module` provides you with two functions to convert a timestamp object to another one corresponding to the same time of day (`from_utc_timesamp`, `to_utc_timestamp`). Although I don't think you want to alter your datetimes.

Comment: Where did you find this information about the conf strings? I couldn't find them anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: It's not documented but there is a pull request for it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18936. I needed it to properly consider data without daylight savings, and there were a few thread on SO setting this configuration namely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434538/change-the-timestamp-to-utc-format-in-pyspark