# Spark getting the current date from another country

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to get the date and time of another country:

```
dateFormat = "%Y%m%d_%H%M"
ts=spark.sql(""" select current_timestamp() as ctime """).collect()[0]["ctime"]
ts.strftime(dateFormat)
```

Comment: Please, could you explain better your question? Do you want a date and time in another timezone?

Comment: yes, i want a date and time in another timezone, thanks

Comment: @DanielAdrianGarayGarcia What Spark version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the timestamp to UTC format in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434538/change-the-timestamp-to-utc-format-in-pyspark)

Comment: No, I want to be able to get the current date and time from China or another country. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need pyspark for such a task, especially when you call .collect():

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')
ts = datetime.now(tz)
ts.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M')
```

Comment: I agree but the question is about achieving in pyspark, as we already know using a external python libraries can affect the performance of a spark application

Comment: @Kris: The question isn't specific about that and you have a negative performance effect every time you move data from the JVM to a python function and back to the JVM. What I have shown has no performance impact at all because the JVM is not involved (it is executed in the spark driver and the data stays there to be specific). What people do with it later (e.g. wrapping it into a udf and applying it to a dataframe), can have a negative performance impact. Maybe you can post your own question, describe your use case and I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

The session time zone is set with the configuration ‘spark.sql.session.timeZone’ and will default to the JVM system local time zone,you can change Time Zone , add your time zone will give you proper date

```
        spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can get current date from utc timestamp in pyspark using below code. Can update the timezone as per requirement.

```
import pytz
current_timestamp_utc = spark.sql("SELECT current_timestamp()").collect()[0][0]
awst_timezone = pytz.timezone('Australia/Perth')
current_date_awst = current_timestamp_utc.astimezone(awst_timezone).date()
```